# Can you set Photoshop to automatically open the file that you "save as.."

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save-as

Can you set Photoshop to automatically open the file when you elect to "save as.." instead of remaining in the not saved file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if I do, the answer is that Photoshop is already doing that.

**Example**

```
1) --a---b
          \
2)         c---d
```

Lets say that *1* and *2* represents different directories, and the letters (*a, b, c, d*) represents a 'Save'. The line that connects the saves represents the current file that Photoshop has open for you.

*a, b* and *d* are regular 'Save' while *c* would be a 'Save As' where you changed the directory you saved the file.